# if else to calculate from a string haskell

Tags: haskell

hi I am new to haskell and very confused about if condition of haskell.
I was trying to calculate a sum from a String of grades. 
For example, `grades "ABC"` should have the result of "128" while A=56,B=40 and C=32.
I am wondering if I am heading to the right direction. I wanted to output the sum of the grades by having sum after `then`
Here is the code I got so far :

```
grades (x:xs) =
 if x=="A" then sum+=56
 else if x=="B" then sum+=40
 else if x=="C" then sum+=32
 else if x=="D" then sum+=24
 else if x=="E" then sum+=8
 else sum+=0
```

Comment: Unrelated to `if then else`. There is no `+=` operator in Haskell. (Well ok, some libraries like Lens define it, but it doesn't do what you think it does.)

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing out that :) . I've just changed my code into sum = sum+56 and so on

Comment: There is no assignment operator `=` either, that symbol can only be used in declarations.

Comment: @Fatball: Like many others here that start Haskell, you write an imperative program in what looks like familiar syntax. Yes, I think the designers of Haskell perhaps better had used different names for these function (this is not an insult or anything). But Haskell is *functional programming*, and that is a (very) different paradigm than *imperative* programming. There is for instance no `for` loop in Haskell either. Therefore I really would advice you to look for a few examples in Haskell instead of the "immediate hands-on approach".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. I would recommend a good book, for example Hutton's *Haskell Programming (2nd edition)*.

```
-- a function to convert grades to points
pts 'A' = 56
pts 'B' = 40
pts 'C' = 32
pts 'D' = 24
pts 'E' = 8
pts _ = 0

-- then your desired function
grades str = sum (map pts str)
-- or, point-free (no pun intended)
grades' = sum . map pts
```

After these definitions

```
λ> map pts "ABC"
[56,40,32]
λ> grades "ABC"
128
```

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: Thank you, totally worked!! I have learnt a lot from your code and the way you think. But what if I wanted to have "A*" (String) than using Char? is that possible? My original purpose was to calculate the sum of the grades then compare to another variable. I have evaluated with your helps so it works totally fine with Char. But what should I do if I wanted to have A* instead of A?

Comment: @Fatball It should work for strings as well, e.g. `pts "A" = 10 ; pts "A*" = 12 ; ...`. Just use double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this but using map and composit functions for a beginner is not a good idea